# Bokeh TapTool to show text in Div when clicked and reset to blank when not clicked

Tags: python, bokeh

this is my first question here, so please let me know if I need to add any details.

I'm experimenting with creating an interactive network graph in Bokeh. I've taken this [simple example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_weighted_graph.html) and am trying to reproduce part of this [example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#interaction-policies), so that when a node is clicked, it and its edges are visible.

I also have a Div which is initially blank which I want to populate when a node is clicked. Right now, I'm able to do just that ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x40ii.png)). However, the text is still there when I deselect the node ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W9Io.png)). I'm fairly clueless when it comes to JS, even though I have some previous experience working with Bokeh for simple plots and interactions, so I am at a bit of a loss on how to proceed.

I've provided the code I've been playing around with below. Using bokeh 1.0.2 and python 3.6.4.

Thanks in advance!

```
import networkx as nx
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Plot, TapTool, ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, StaticLayoutProvider, Circle, MultiLine
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
from bokeh.models.graphs import NodesAndLinkedEdges, EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.renderers import GraphRenderer, GlyphRenderer
from bokeh.layouts import layout, row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 0.5]

for u,v in G.edges():
    G[u][v]['color'] = 'red' if G[u][v]['weight'] <= 0.5 else 'black'

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

node_ids = list(G.nodes())
start_ids = [a for a,b in G.edges()]
end_ids = [b for a,b in G.edges()]
weights = [10*G[a][b]['weight'] for a,b in G.edges()]
colors = [G[a][b]['color'] for a,b in G.edges()]

graph_layout = pos
label_layout = pos
x_graph, y_graph = [v[0] for v in graph_layout.values()], [v[1] for v in graph_layout.values()]
x_label, y_label = [v[0] for v in label_layout.values()], [v[1] for v in label_layout.values()]


node_ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(index=list(G.nodes()),
                                     x = x_graph,
                                     y = y_graph,
                                     color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'orange', 'grey']),
                           name="Node Renderer")
edge_ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(start= start_ids,
                                      end=end_ids,
                                      weight = weights,
                                      color = colors),
                            name="Edge Renderer")

graph_plot = GraphRenderer(node_renderer=GlyphRenderer(glyph=Circle(size=15, fill_color="color"),
                                                       selection_glyph=Circle(size=15, fill_color="color"),
                                                  data_source=node_ds),
                      edge_renderer=GlyphRenderer(glyph=MultiLine(line_alpha=0.4, line_width= 'weight', line_color = 'color'),
                                                  selection_glyph=MultiLine(line_alpha=1, line_width = 'weight', line_color = 'color'),
                                                  nonselection_glyph=MultiLine(line_alpha=0, line_width = 'weight', line_color = 'color'),
                                                  data_source=edge_ds),
                      layout_provider=StaticLayoutProvider(graph_layout=graph_layout),
                      selection_policy=NodesAndLinkedEdges())

label_ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(index=list(G.nodes()),
                                      x = x_label,
                                      y = y_label))
labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='index', source=label_ds,
                  background_fill_color='lightgrey')

div = Div(text='', width=300)

plot = figure(x_range=(-1,1), y_range=(-1.1,1.1), plot_width=400, plot_height=400, name='main_plot')
plot.add_tools(TapTool(callback=CustomJS(args={'div': div}, code="""
    String.prototype.format = function() {
      a = this;
      for (k in arguments) {
        a = a.replace("{" + k + "}", arguments[k])
      }
      return a
    }
    var ind = cb_data.source.selected['1d'].indices;
    var color = cb_data.source.data['color'][ind];
    var name = cb_data.source.data['index'][ind];
    div.text = 'This is node {0}, it is colored {1}'.format(name, color);
""")))
plot.renderers.append(graph_plot)
plot.renderers.append(labels)
layout=row(plot,div)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually got this to work by simply adding the following:

```
plot.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args={'src': node_ds, 'div': div}, code="""
    if (src.selected.indices.length == 0){
        div.text = '';
    }
"""))
```

I don't know if that's the *best* way to do it, but it works for now.